# GTM - iOS Custom Tag is not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, google-tag-manager

Confirm the tag setup and the version is published
[image]

Confirm the Class Name is correct

```
import Foundation
import GoogleTagManager
import Branch

@objc(CustomEventTagFunction)
final class CustomEventTagFunction : NSObject, TAGCustomFunction {
    @objc func execute(withParameters parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]!) -> NSObject! {
        print("it works")
        return nil
    }
}
```

See the event is logged with output:

```
2020-09-25 17:40:31.908572+0800 test-wryg[63300:473903] GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: gtm_test with parameters: {
    "_sc" = DemoViewController;
    "_si" = 8977004208359017134;
    name = jeff;
}
```

But the "it works" is not print out from custom, is anything I should check?

thanks

Comment: come back next day and it works. ; D

Answer (score 0):

seems related to the container is not updated to newest version. To resolve this:

1. wait for update

from Google’s document

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5

> Note: For mobile containers, a default container is used to set
> initial tag configurations until the first time a container is
> downloaded. Once the app has connected to the internet and downloaded
> a container, it will never use the default container again.
> Applications periodically check for container updates, typically every
> 12 hours.

2. remove the app/cache to focus update